# css -not selector- breaks precedence?

Tags: html, css

In a css file, the last defined style takes precedence over previous defined ones.

But when using the `not selector`, the precedence gets broken and the class with the `not selector` gets precedence even though it's located at the top of the file.

**What's the logic behind the precedence break?**

[Example:](http://plnkr.co/edit/tPWQav?p=preview)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
      .red-with-not:not(.something) {
        background: red;
      }
      .red {
        background: red;
      }
      .blue {
        background: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="base">
    <h1 class="blue red-with-not">Expected Blue - PROBLEM</h1>
    <h1 class="blue red">Expected Blue - Great!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You say:

> In a css file, the last defined style takes precedence over previous
>   defined ones

Not so fast... a class with higher specificity takes precedence over the order in which the classes appear in the CSS! ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#cascading) - Notice how **'specificity'** appears before **'order of appearance'** in the list)

So how would you calculate the specificity of the above classes?

From the [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity):

> Selectors inside the negation pseudo-class are counted like any other,
>   but the negation itself does not count as a pseudo-class.

So the specificity of the selector `.red-with-not:not(.something)` =

```
/* a=0 b=2 c=0 -> specificity = 020 (two class selectors) */
```

Where

`a` = # ID selectors in the selector,

`b` = # class selectors, attributes selectors, and pseudo-classes in the selector and

`c` = # type selectors and pseudo-elements in the selector

As apposed to the other selectors `.red` and `.blue` - which have a specificity of only 010 (one class selector).

---

In case you're interested, [specificity calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/) is a good reference for calculating specificity.

Answer (score 4):

The specificity for `.red-with-not:not(.something)` comes out to be '0020' while for `.red` or `.blue` comes out to be '0010'. Hence, precedence is given to `.red-with-not:not(.something)`.

[image]

[image]

Please refer [Specifics on CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) for more understanding.